# /var/log/syslog equivalent in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am  new to iPhone/iOS environment, on the Mac I could see the system logs like /var/log/system.log, and of course in linux /var/log/syslog.

How do i view the same log files on the iPhone? But first of all, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open xcode, go to Organizer (CMD + SHIFT + 2), and there you can see Device Logs under your iphone. There you can visualize all logs for each app you use.

Comment: Any way to get this for the simulator?